# How do I get to Kala'e Bay?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

On Melemele Island, there's a patch of ocean with some Pokémon like Shellder and Mareanie. On the map, it's called Kala'e Bay. How exactly do I get down there? From what I can see, there is a cave entrance/exit down there, but I'm not sure what it's connected to. Does anyone know how to get there?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After you get Lapras added to your Ride Pager, you can explore Kala'e Bay, which you can reach from Melemele Meadow and Seaward Cave.

**How to reach Kala'e Bay**
Go to Melemele Meadow on Melemele Island. Go southwest through the flowers to find a hole in the left wall. Go into the hole, then go south until the path splits. From there, go east down a series of one-way ledges. Then follow the path to find a cave exit. Go out from there to reach Kala'e Bay.

**This is what you can find there**
You can get a Dive Ball from the large island in the middle, and there is a hidden Big Pearl on the rock south of there.
There is a Poké Finder spot on the right side of the bay.
There is a beach in the southern part of the bay where you can get a hidden Pearl.
On the south end of that beach, you will find find TM05 Roar.

[Source](http://www.thonky.com/pokemon-sun-moon/kalae-bay)

Comment: Just to clarify, Lapras isn't necessary to reach Kala'e Bay, and the Zygarde Cell can be picked up without it, although not much else can be done there without Lapras.

Comment: Also, as @Chuck noted, the video might be inappropriate for some audiences and the answer already contains all relevant information, so you might want to consider removing the reference. It's not like this information is particularly hard to find, it's on most fansites that have sun/moon content, so the citation isn't really necessary here.

Comment: @scenia removed the video. Thanks for bringing it up.